# Teradata 15: how to FAST LOAD xlsx?

Tags: teradata, ctl, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to load data to Teradata directly from xlsx with FAST LOAD.
Receiving the empty table and following error in CTL log:

```
**** 16:09:28 Number of recs/msg: 10
**** 16:09:28 Starting to send to RDBMS with record 1
**** 16:09:28 Error on piom GET ROW: 61, Text: Warning, too few columns
              !ERROR! Delimited Data Parsing error: Too few columns in
              row 1
**** 16:09:28 Error at record number 1
**** 16:09:28 Error on piom GET ROW: 61, Text: Warning, too few columns
              !ERROR! Delimited Data Parsing error: Too few columns in
              row 2
```

The datafile is good, loads normally if converted to csv, but I need it to be loaded from xlsx in order to minimize manual operations.

I guess that the delimiter was chosen incorrectly—It's ";", just as for CSV.
What delimiter should I use? Or maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: XLSX is not a format supported by FastLoad.

Comment: A wicked method that might work for you is to open the file in sas via an odbc source, and then fastload the work sas set into TD.